# Firebase role based access with React (asynchronous woes)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, state

This is a slightly longwinded one, I'll aim for brevity but will obviously provide more info if I've missed anything.

I am creating a mock "bug reporting app". This app has 2 "types" of user - "user" and "engineer". The plan is to use these types, once in the context or local state, to conditionally render routes. Upon signing up the userType is stored inside the user document in firebase:

```
9AytcWiVI4OghrYzf8Jl7BeYhlb2 <-uid
displayName: "eng1"
online: true
photoURL: "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/bottts/eng1.svg"
userType: "engineer"
```

I am trying to collect the "userType" from the doc, based on the current user, and store it in state, but I'm having real trouble and I think it's from synchronicity or lack of it.

Currently I store a firebase user object in context:

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
import { projectAuth } from '../firebase/config'

export const AuthContext = createContext()

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return { ...state, user: action.payload }
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return { ...state, user: null }
    case 'AUTH_IS_READY':
      return { user: action.payload, authIsReady: true }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, { 
    user: null,
    authIsReady: false
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_IS_READY', payload: user })
      unsub()
    })
  }, [])

  console.log('AuthContext state:', state)
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )

}
```

I can call this in any component easily enough, and access user.uid again easily enough, and it can be console logged 100% of the time.

I then try to use that user.uid to access the user document, to access the "userType" key, but it "cannot read property" when previously it did.

I have been tearing my hair out as to how to work around this but, again, I think it's trying to access user.uid before it's actually accessed it

Any and all help is appreciated.

***EDIT for clarification***

The user enters their email address and password to login, which calls my useLogin hook.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { projectAuth, projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'
import { useAuthContext } from './useAuthContext'

export const useLogin = () => {
  const [isCancelled, setIsCancelled] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false)
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    setError(null)
    setIsPending(true)
  
    try {
      // login
      const res = await projectAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)


      //update online status on the database
      await projectFirestore.collection("users").doc(res.user.uid).update({online: true})
      

      // dispatch login action
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.user })

      if (!isCancelled) {
        setIsPending(false)
        setError(null)
      }
    } 
    catch(err) {
      if (!isCancelled) {
        setError(err.message)
        setIsPending(false)

      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setIsCancelled(true)
  }, [])

  return { login, isPending, error }
}
```

And there are two hooks for accessing the firestore database, useCollection:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config"

export const useCollection = (collection) => { //,_query
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(null)

  const [error, setError] = useState(null)


  // const query = useRef(_query).current
  // const orderBy = useRef(_orderBy).current

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = projectFirestore.collection(collection)

    // if (query) {
    //   ref = ref.where(...query)
    // }
    // if (orderBy) {
    //   ref = ref.orderBy(...orderBy)
    // }


    const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      let results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        results.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})
      });
      
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)

      setError(null)
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
      setError('could not fetch the data')
    })

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe()

  }, [collection]) // orderBy, query, 

  return { documents, error }
}
```

And useDocument:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config"


export const useDocument = (collection, id) => {

  const [document, setDocument] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  // realtime document data
  useEffect(() => {
    const ref = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

    const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      // need to make sure the doc exists & has data

      if(snapshot.data()) {
        setDocument({...snapshot.data(), id: snapshot.id})
        setError(null)
        
      }
      else {
        setError('No such document exists')
      }
    }, err => {
      console.log(err.message)
      setError('failed to get document')
    })

    // unsubscribe on unmount
    return () => unsubscribe()

  }, [collection, id])

  return { document, error }
}
```

A dummy component file I've created to try and work it out:

```
import {React, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useAuthContext } from '../../hooks/useAuthContext'
import { useDocument } from '../../hooks/useDocument'




export default function User() {
    const { user } = useAuthContext();
    console.log("uid: " + user.uid)

    const id = user.uid;
    console.log("id: " + id)

    let { document, error } = useDocument("users", id)
    console.log("userType: " + document.userType)

  return (
    <div>


    </div>
  )
}
```

Upon first completion of the file, it goes through useDocument just fine and returns all the information as requested. But on reload of the app I get the following error/s:

```
User.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'userType')
    at User (User.js:16:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
User @ User.js:16
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:14985
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:17811
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:19049
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22293
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21893
dispatchAction @ react-dom.development.js:16139
(anonymous) @ AuthContext.js:27
(anonymous) @ subscribe.ts:104
(anonymous) @ subscribe.ts:233
Promise.then (async)
ObserverProxy.sendOne @ subscribe.ts:230
ObserverProxy.forEachObserver @ subscribe.ts:220
ObserverProxy.next @ subscribe.ts:103
(anonymous) @ auth.js:1532
(anonymous) @ auth.js:1996
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:475
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:469
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:924
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:611
Dd @ eventtarget.js:336
H.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:460
li @ xhrio.js:864
k.Jc @ xhrio.js:811
k.Vb @ xhrio.js:788
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
ei @ xhrio.js:607
Ii.u @ rpchandler.js:644
Si @ rpchandler.js:549
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:921
D @ promise.js:164
Yi @ rpchandler.js:920
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:2677
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:567
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:486
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:469
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
d.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:318
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:292
D @ promise.js:164
tk @ indexeddb.js:291
uk @ indexeddb.js:346
c @ indexeddb.js:364
D @ promise.js:164
vk @ indexeddb.js:386
k.set @ indexeddb.js:465
(anonymous) @ hybridindexeddb.js:70
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
E @ promise.js:346
Ck @ hybridindexeddb.js:57
Tk @ authstorage.js:191
Vk @ authstorage.js:234
un @ storageusermanager.js:90
En @ auth.js:121
instanceFactory @ exports_auth.js:759
Provider.getOrInitializeService @ provider.ts:302
Provider.getImmediate @ provider.ts:115
instanceFactory @ exports_auth.js:771
Provider.getOrInitializeService @ provider.ts:302
Provider.getImmediate @ provider.ts:115
t @ prebuilt.js:14376
t @ prebuilt.js:14644
e @ prebuilt.js:15237
(anonymous) @ index.ts:39
(anonymous) @ config.ts:80
Provider.getOrInitializeService @ provider.ts:302
Provider.getImmediate @ provider.ts:115
FirebaseAppImpl._getService @ firebaseApp.ts:126
firebaseAppImpl.<computed> @ firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:228
serviceNamespace @ firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:209
./src/firebase/config.js @ config.js:19
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/context/AuthContext.js @ UsersBar.js:7
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/hooks/useAuthContext.js @ config.js:27
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/App.js @ dash.svg:34
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/index.js @ useSignup.js:9
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
Show 47 more frames
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 The above error occurred in the <User> component:

    at User (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:935:76)
    at div
    at Dashboard (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2514:74)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87145:5)
    at div
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87078:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86554:5)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:159:76)
    at AuthContextProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1172:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:3973
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20118
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20736
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21893
dispatchAction @ react-dom.development.js:16139
(anonymous) @ AuthContext.js:27
(anonymous) @ subscribe.ts:104
(anonymous) @ subscribe.ts:233
Promise.then (async)
ObserverProxy.sendOne @ subscribe.ts:230
ObserverProxy.forEachObserver @ subscribe.ts:220
ObserverProxy.next @ subscribe.ts:103
(anonymous) @ auth.js:1532
(anonymous) @ auth.js:1996
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:475
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:469
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:924
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:611
Dd @ eventtarget.js:336
H.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:460
li @ xhrio.js:864
k.Jc @ xhrio.js:811
k.Vb @ xhrio.js:788
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
ei @ xhrio.js:607
Ii.u @ rpchandler.js:644
Si @ rpchandler.js:549
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:921
D @ promise.js:164
Yi @ rpchandler.js:920
(anonymous) @ rpchandler.js:2677
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:567
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:545
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:486
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
a.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:441
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:469
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
(anonymous) @ promise.js:167
d.onsuccess @ indexeddb.js:318
IndexedDB (async)
(anonymous) @ indexeddb.js:292
D @ promise.js:164
tk @ indexeddb.js:291
uk @ indexeddb.js:346
c @ indexeddb.js:364
D @ promise.js:164
vk @ indexeddb.js:386
k.set @ indexeddb.js:465
(anonymous) @ hybridindexeddb.js:70
e.g @ promise.js:826
Sc @ promise.js:1165
Oc @ promise.js:1136
k.gc @ promise.js:1107
xc @ run.js:124
Promise.then (async)
uc @ run.js:55
tc @ run.js:32
Pc @ promise.js:1027
zc @ promise.js:900
E @ promise.js:346
Ck @ hybridindexeddb.js:57
Tk @ authstorage.js:191
Vk @ authstorage.js:234
un @ storageusermanager.js:90
En @ auth.js:121
instanceFactory @ exports_auth.js:759
Provider.getOrInitializeService @ provider.ts:302
Provider.getImmediate @ provider.ts:115
instanceFactory @ exports_auth.js:771
Provider.getOrInitializeService @ provider.ts:302
Provider.getImmediate @ provider.ts:115
t @ prebuilt.js:14376
t @ prebuilt.js:14644
e @ prebuilt.js:15237
(anonymous) @ index.ts:39
(anonymous) @ config.ts:80
Provider.getOrInitializeService @ provider.ts:302
Provider.getImmediate @ provider.ts:115
FirebaseAppImpl._getService @ firebaseApp.ts:126
firebaseAppImpl.<computed> @ firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:228
serviceNamespace @ firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:209
./src/firebase/config.js @ config.js:19
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/context/AuthContext.js @ UsersBar.js:7
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/hooks/useAuthContext.js @ config.js:27
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/App.js @ dash.svg:34
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:61
./src/index.js @ useSignup.js:9
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
Show 47 more frames
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'userType')
    at User (User.js:16:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

The fact it works, then upon reload doesn't work, makes me suspect I could fix it with asynchronicity(??) but I just can't figure out how.

Comment: I don't see any of this code accessing a Firebase database. Can you point out which exact line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? Are there any error messages? If so, what are the exact, complete error message and stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me quickly, Frank. I have edited my original question to add a lot of clarity. Apologies if anything's missing, I will again happily put more information if required.

Comment: It looks like `document` is not initialized by the time you try to use it. If that is coming from the database, are you sure a document with the requested ID exists?  --- Note that by now we have quite some code and multiple files, which makes it hard to help. So if the above doesn't help you solve it, I recommend trying to isolate the problem - reproducing in as little code as possible. For more hints on why and how to do this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is a document of that id in the database, and when the code is first entered, and VSCode does a live reload, the data is called succesfully. It's only upon saving and refreshing that it doesn't work.

The issue from experimentation is that user.uid isn't initialised in time, but I don't know how to implement asynchronous functions which can call upon react hooks.

Anyway I'll keep trying and thanks for the help.